# how to deal with the unknown id with ember-data and emberjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, ember.js, ember-data, routes

## Based on Rails, Emberjs and ember-data

## Route

```js
App.Router.map ->
  @resource "sentences", ->
    @resource "sentence",
      path: ":sentence_id", ->
```

## Model

```
App.Sentence = DS.Model.extend(
  subject: DS.attr("string")
)
```

## visit the url

```
http://localhost:3000/#/sentences/5
```

## if the sentence with the id 5 does not exist in the server, how to deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

If your server sends a 404, for such a request, Ember will raise an exception which can be handled via an `errors` handler on the route. From there you can display this in the UI or `transitionTo` another route that can display the error.

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    error: function(reason, transition) {
      // display error or transitionTo here
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there a specific version of Ember, or Ember Data that this works with? I'm using 
Ember: 1.0.0-rc.4 and Ember Data r13 and it's triggering the error event on my Route.

Comment: This is from RC.6. It's from the Async Router Facelift, no direct dependency on ember-data.

Comment: Thanks Darshan...we can't upgrade to RC6 yet because of a limitation in Ember Data.

Answer (score 0):

how to use the two params 'reason', 'transition' 
Is it possible to show one example

why does it have two params here?

Comment: `reason` is the error object from jQuery. `transition` is the Routers transition object that was being changed to, before the error. It's mostly internal to the Router, see [this](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/19271bcbdaca6f6369169c07603566d6b535c888/packages/ember-routing/lib/vendor/router.js#L29)